SharpGL Texture Loading
I am trying to load an MTL file to an OBJ using SharpGL, but for some reason, the texture doesn't load correctly and all my scene gets darker.
Here is my code!
        private int LoadTexture(OpenGL gl, string texturePath)
        {
            if (textureCache.TryGetValue(texturePath, out uint textureId))
            {
                // Return the cached texture ID if it's already loaded
                return (int)textureId;
            }
 
            // Generate a texture ID and bind it
            uint[] textures = new uint[1];
            gl.GenTextures(1, textures);
            textureId = textures[0];
 
            gl.BindTexture(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
 
            // Load the image from file
            try
            {
                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(texturePath))
                {
                    BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                                                      ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                                      PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
 
                    // Set the texture parameters
                    gl.TexParameter(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, OpenGL.GL_LINEAR);
                    gl.TexParameter(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, OpenGL.GL_LINEAR);
                    gl.TexParameter(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, OpenGL.GL_REPEAT);
                    gl.TexParameter(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, OpenGL.GL_REPEAT);
 
                    // Create the texture from the bitmap data
                    gl.TexImage2D(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, OpenGL.GL_RGBA, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, 0,
                                  OpenGL.GL_BGRA, OpenGL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data.Scan0);
 
                    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to load texture {texturePath}: {ex.Message}");
                return 0;
            }
 
            // Cache the loaded texture ID
            textureCache[texturePath] = textureId;
 
            return (int)textureId;
        }
    }



I have trying anything beacuse I dont know what is wrong ‍♂️. Is the first time I use SharpGL and I don't know what I am doing wrong.
